# Method resolution order in Python - in absence of constructor in child and parent left class

Tags: python

This is about Method resolution order in Python. Lets say we have 3 classes: A, B, C.

C(A,B) - multiple inheritance.

In the absence of constructor in the child class C, and parent left class A, does the python engine look for the constructor from the RHS class B and execute it if it is present OR does it look to see if A has any parent class with constructor?

Example: What if Class A inherits from Class X that has a constructor. Then will the constructor from Class X run or the constructor from Class B run?

Comment: adding the workable code will be benefical

Answer (score 1):

```
class A:
    pass

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        print("I am class B")

class C(A, B):
    pass

print(C())
```

```
I am class B
```

With this other example, you will understand better how multiple inheritance works:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print("I am class A")

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        print("I am class B")

class C(A, B):
    pass

print(C())
```

```
I am class A
```

As you can see, B `__init__` didn't get called, this is because parent classes are called from left to right, but each one must not forget to call "super init", otherwise it breaks the inheritance chain

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print("I am class A")
        super().__init__()

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        print("I am class B")

class C(A, B):
    pass

print(C())
```

```
I am class A
I am class B
```

Comment: it;s better if you add little explanation and resoultion order also explation

Comment: Edited with more explanations

Comment: What you mean by " but each one must not forget to call "super init""

Comment: I mean the parent `__init__`. Based on MRO (Method Resolution Order), a call to `super().method(...)` automatically calls the method of the next class from inheritance chain.